# IIS Manager Error

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hi buddies i m new to ASP.NET.While i'm hosting my website in IIS(Internet Information Service),I'm getting an error as in the below picture...what should i do to fix it?I gotta tired after struggled with my codes and a lot.

[image: My Issue]

Comment: Google "iis manager used by another process", people already had this issue and posted how to fix it. In short: most probably your 80/443 ports are taken by another application.

Comment: I believe Skype steals port 80, so that's likely what it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865272/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there is another application that is using port 80. If you change the bindings for the website to something other than 80 it will work.

You can also do the following to free up port 80:

Run NETSTAT -ano in command prompt and find out the PID for the process that is using port 80. Open up the task manager and in the Services tab find that PID to see what application it is.